# How to build C# Windows Form App as one executable without .dll files?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, exe

I'm building my own Visual Studio Windows Form App with C# but I want o build it as one .exe without all the DLLs I'm using. Is that possible?
Thanks!

Comment: [.NET application publishing overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/)

Comment: Note that you haven't specified the .Net version you're targeting. This detail should not be missing.